# Information from Unix Host

Tags: networking

The following info is from a UNIX host with a IP of 205.133.127.8/24 and a gateway of 205.133.127.1

```
(205.133.127.1) at 0:50:54:7b:e8:c0
(205.133.127.4) at 0:10:1f:52:10:0
(205.133.127.6) at 0:60:8:93:37:b5
(205.133.127.7) at 0:0:f4:c8:9f:6a
(205.133.127.8) at 0:60:8:93:38:c2
(205.133.127.9) at 0:60:8:93:38:db
(205.133.127.10)at 0:50:da:b:23:c9
...
(205.133.127.76) at 8:0:20:b:6d:b9
(205.133.127.84) at 0:c0:5:4:14:17
(205.133.127.85) at 0:c0:5:4:1e:19
...
(205.133.127.214)at (incomplete)
(205.133.127.234)at 0:40:33:ca:a1:5d
(205.133.127.238)at 0:60:97:79:2:8a
(205.133.127.255) at ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

What does this mean? 
For this line (205.133.127.4) at 0:10:1f:52:10:0, What is this part  0:10:1f:52:10:0. showing?

Describe the events that will happen if the host had packets going to 205.133.127.84, 205.133.127.83, or 205.133.181.3?
What is the difference from these?
205.133.127.84 is the only line that shows up on my list.Does this signify something?

Comment: Where did you get this? You don't say it, but it looks like an `arp` table... But I don't really understand the question, anyway. Maybe you can try and rewrite it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a list of Mac addresses and matching IP addresses.

If the host wants to send to a IP address that's in that list, and if there is a route to it in the routing table then it would eventually use that address.

See `man arp` for full details